# WPF-LiveCharts Legend not update

Tags: wpf, livecharts

Code First: https://github.com/ShannonZ/playground

I use a listbox serve as a clickable legend so that the visibility can be controlled.

I've added a button to modify the series but after that the legend (ListBox Item) did not update. I've traced into LiveCharts.Helpers.NoisyCollection and found the implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged Interface.

Any one can help to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the button you added to update the listbox which is your legend?

Your converter seems to be causing the problem. By removing the converter from the xaml binding you get the desired result.

```
ItemsSource={Binding Series}
```

Comment: I've bind the ItemSource of ListBox with the prop Series, why need to add this line：ListBox.ItemSource = Series;

Comment: @ShannonChow apologies, when going through your code I missed something important. The seriescollection has been designed by LiveCharts to update automatically. By binding to the listbox as you have done, this update mechanism does indeed work correctly. This line `ListBox.ItemSource = Series; ` is NOT required, this was my mistake. I have found that the issue is being cause by your ReverseConverter. I am not quite sure what its purpose is for but removing it from your xaml binding you will notice that the code runs and does what you expect. `ItemsSource={Binding Series}` is all you need.

Comment: @ShannonChow My pleasure, could you please mark the answer as 'accepted' for any future reference. Thanks